# Скопировать scipy из Anaconda в Miniconda

Tags: python, scipy

У меня установлены Anaconda и Miniconda. Мне необходимо перенести scipy из Anaconda в Miniconda. Реально ли это сделать? Просто я работаю с Miniconda, а в ней нет scipy, а отдельно установить не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Скопируйте `.\scipy` в папку `.\Python\Lib\site-packages`.

Если при работе с этой библиотекой потребуются дополнения, можно и их скопировать аналогичным способом.

Comment: @tovarich_Kirov при копировании работает без ошибок?

Comment: Да, пока без ошибок